# ¿como enviar/cifrar un mensaje en Angular 8, enviarlo POST, y que mi Back End en STS lo autorice? ¿Bcrytjs funciona en Angular y Spring Java?

Tags: java, angular, post, cifrado, bcryptjs

Estoy haciendo una página Web en Angular 8 (Front End), que se conecta con REST (post,get..) con el Back End que va en Java (Spring Tool Suite), este Back End se conecta con una BBDD MySQL. Tengo que hacer una operación de LOG IN utilizando por ejemplo, una pasword del cliente y su email.
     Veo la maneras de enfocarlo:
           Enviar el mensaje post cifrado y que mi Back End en Java lo descifre y haga la verificación enviando la respuesta.
Envío en Angular así,

```
 onSubmit() : void {    
    this.userLogin=this.myLoginForm.value;
    this.userLogin.id=0;
    console.log("user LOGIN  es => " , this.userLogin);
    this._postLoginService.autentificarUsuario( this.userLogin).subscribe(data=>{

      this.data=data

    console.log ( "TERMINO POST. Mi usuario ID es: ",  data);///camnio
    })
   }
```

mi servicio en Angular ( sin terminar, quiero que devuelva un numero y si el numero es mayor que 0 es un ID correcto, esta en OBRAS) es:

```
autentificarUsuario(userLogin: IloginUsuario): Observable <BigInteger>{
        console.log("Dentro Servicio de autenficación de usuario  ",userLogin);

        return this.http.post (this._url, userLogin).pipe(
            map((respuesta:any)=>{
                //Aqui puedes trabajar los datos y hacer lo que quieras
                console.log( "ver que tengo ", respuesta);
                    if(respuesta==null){
                    console.log( "Error usuario mal autenticado", respuesta);
                    }else{
                    console.log( "Usuario inscrito OK", respuesta);    
                    }
                return this.respuesta;
            }),
            catchError(err=> {
                //Esto te permite capturar todos los errores 
                // o cualquier logica que quieras
                console.log( "Error al hacer login usuario ", err );
                return throwError(err)
            }) 
            )
```

y recibo ,

```
user LOGIN  es =>  {email: "nom3@gmail.com", password: "123455676", id: 0}
UsuarioRegistrado.Service.ts:15 Dentro Servicio de autenficación de usuario   {email: "nom3@gmail.com", password: "123455676", id: 0}
UsuarioRegistrado.Service.ts:20 ver que tengo  69
UsuarioRegistrado.Service.ts:24 Usuario inscrito OK 69
login.component.ts:41 TERMINO POST. Mi usuario ID es:  undefined
```

Aquí podemos ver que el servidor de Back End me devuelve 69 que es el ID del usuario haciendo Login.
Mi problema es que es post básicamente lo hago como en el hilo: [Angular POST, no espera resultado operación. ¿Por qué?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/328589/angular-post-no-espera-resultado-operaci%C3%B3n-por-qu%C3%A9/328651#328651)
Evidentemente, el Jasón que envió no esta cifrado. Necesito algo para enviar un POST que proteja la información y que mi servidor en STS Java pueda entender.

Supongo algun tipo de operación de hash o cifrado hay ya en alguna libreria. O alguna opción de hacer un post así.
Tengo muchas dudas,
(*) no se si lo correcto es hacer un jason que tenga un campo para email y otro para password, encriptarlo en Angular y mandarlo al servidor de Back end en Spring y allí desencriptarlo o es mejor encriptar solamente el campo password. Ejemplo,

```
export interface IloginUsuario{
    id: number,
    email: string,
    password: string
}
```

La respuesta consistirá en el ID del usuario (clave primaria de la BBDD) si existe, y otros mensajes de no existir ese usuario.
(*) Otra pregunta será si Bcrytjs se puede implementar sin problemas es angular y java.
La cosa es que no encuentro algo claro. ¿puede alguién darme un consejo y un ejemplo de como hacer en lado Angular y en lado STS?
Lo único que se me ocurre sencillo es hacerme yo alguna función que lo haga, pero seguro que es una chapuza y poco profesional. Quiero aprender a hacer algo medianamente aceptable . Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo, tu código está bien pero tiene un pequeño fallo:

```
    ...
    map((respuesta:any)=>{ //La función recibe un parámetro respuesta
        //Aqui puedes trabajar los datos y hacer lo que quieras
        console.log( "ver que tengo ", respuesta);
            if(respuesta==null){
            console.log( "Error usuario mal autenticado", respuesta);
            }else{
            console.log( "Usuario inscrito OK", respuesta);    
            }
        //en lugar de devolver el parámetro, devuelves un propiedad del servicio
        return this.respuesta;
    }),
```

Si quitas el `this` debería funcionar. De hecho no deberías tener ninguna propiedad `respuesta` en el servicio.

Por otro lado, no es necesario cifrar el usuario y contraseña del usuario. De hecho, es inútil, porque tendrías que tener la contraseña en la aplicación Angular, con lo que sería pública. Lo que tienes que hacer es mandar esos datos al *backend* en plano (en un entorno real los datos ya irán cifrados por el protocolo HTTPS) y que el backend realice las operaciones necesarias para comprobar que el usuario y contraseña coinciden.

Comment: Gracias por decirme lo del this de más. Efectivamente. Hay que quitarlo y así me sale el valor que da de respuesta el Back    …   Entiendo que si va con protocolo HTTPS es como dices, pero.....  entonces  es mejor una contraseña (que tendrá que guardarse cifrada en el sistema). En la BBDD solamente. ¿no?.