# ¿Como utilizar una cookie en Angular 8?

Tags: cookies, variables-globales, angular8, component, binding

Tengo el componente app donde he creado una cookie.

```
@Component({
 // selector: 'app-root',
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'uned-frontEnd';


      constructor ( private cookieSvc: CookieService){
    }

    ngOnInit():void{
      this.cookieSvc.set('UserAutenticado','noAutenticado',0.3);
      console.log (this.cookieSvc.get('UserAutenticado'));
      //this.cookieSvc.delete('UserAutenticado');

    }

}
```

Quiero utilizar una Cookie donde me almacena el ID de un usuario cuando este haga Login contra un servidor de Back End. 
Eso lo genera una clase servicio que realiza el post.

```
autentificarUsuario(userLogin: IloginUsuario): Observable <BigInteger>{
        console.log("Dentro Servicio de autenficación de usuario  ",userLogin);

        return this.http.post (this._url, userLogin).pipe(
            map((respuesta:any)=>{
                //Aqui puedes trabajar los datos y hacer lo que quieras
                console.log( "ver que tengo ", respuesta);
                    if(respuesta==null){
                    console.log( "Error usuario mal autenticado", respuesta);
                    }else{
                    console.log( "Usuario inscrito OK", respuesta); 
                    this.cookieSvc.set('UserAutenticado',respuesta,0.3); 

                    }


                    return respuesta;
            }),
            catchError(err=> {
                //Esto te permite capturar todos los errores 
                // o cualquier logica que quieras
                console.log( "Error al hacer login usuario ", err );
                return throwError(err)
            }) 
            )

    }
```

la explicación completa de como se realiza el post esta en el link

[Angular POST, no espera resultado operación. ¿Por qué?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/328589/angular-post-no-espera-resultado-operaci%C3%B3n-por-qu%C3%A9/328651?noredirect=1#comment596691_328651)

mi problema es que la respuesta de ese post ( el ID de usuario) quiero tenerlo disponible en una "variable global (supongo tipo cookie)" para poder controlarla en cualquier componente de la aplicación.
De todas formas es la manera que se me ocurre de compartir información de la sesión, si hay otra instruirme encantado de aprender.

De paso, ¿Cuál es la manera de compartir las variables de un componente en otro componente en Angular?. ¿Se puede configurar o hacer algún Binding global?

No conozco tanto Angular como para saber hacerlo, estoy aprendiendo. Si puedes darme algún consejo lo agradecería. Gracias

NOTA: Una manera de usar variable global es definir un script en index.html

```
<script>
  let idInIndex;
</script>
```

y luego en tu componente declararlo y usarlo.  Se declara debajo de los import.

```
declare let idInIndex: any;
```

Y luego en el componente lo usas.

```
 console.warn(idInIndex);
 idInIndex=respuesta;
 console.warn(idInIndex);
```

Mi problema es que quiero que mantenga el valor mientras navega o tenga la sesión abierta. Incluso lo suyo es que se borre al cabo de un tiempo. Y usando de esa manera la variable global. No es posible mantener el valor.

Creo que debo usar cookies pero no se como usar una cookie que defino en un modulo y que pueda usar en todos los componentes y la aplicación.

Aclaración:

Por culpa mía al plantear la pregunta ( no tanto por el texto) he recibido alguna respuesta muy interesante y que "TENGO" que estudiar ya que me ha enseñando. Pero me responden a parte, ¿Como usar y hacer variables globales?. Mi problema era que debo tener en toda la sesión ciertos datos para saber que el usuario se ha identificado y que puede hacer ciertas operaciones. Di dos posibles enfoques:
a) guardar datos en variables globales que es lo que he tenido feedback (muchas gracias).
b) uso de cookies pero teniendo acceso desde toda la aplicación.

Voy a intentar usar lo que me sugieren, pero no se si es posible usar cookies como si fuesen variables globales.

Sigo investigando y necesitando vuestra ayuda.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Voy a responder a mi pregunta. La verdad es que quizás era un problema de entender el concepto más que de dificultad. Yo pensé que generando a cookie tenia o debía tener un alcance global de los diferentes "campos" o variables que esa cookie generase. Eso es así pero requiere un paso previo. 
No enseño a instalar cookies ya que en esta web hay muchos y buenos tutoriales. 
yo me lo cree en un componente app.component.ts

```
      constructor ( private cookieSvc: CookieService){
    }

    ngOnInit():void{
      if (this.cookieSvc.get("UserAutenticado") == null) {
      this.cookieSvc.set('UserAutenticado','noAutenticado',0.00000000001);
      console.log (this.cookieSvc.get('UserAutenticado'));
      } else {
        console.log ("El usuario esta autenticado con id: " + this.cookieSvc.get('UserAutenticado'));
      }
```

Lo quería usar en otros componentes. 
Voy al grano. Tendremos en app.module.ts ....

```
 providers: [CookieService,hilosEnfermedadesService,post_inscripcion_usuario,UsuarioRegistradoService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Para poder acceder a ella en otro componente necesitamos poner en import

```
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service';
```

y en constructor :

```
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private cookSvc: CookieService){}
```

ahora tenemos cooksrc y cookieSvc , uno en un componente y otro en el que quiero tenga acceso a la cookie.

Ahora simplemente con get o set, accedo o altero el valor de los "campos" o "variables"
creadas.

```
this.cookSvc.set("UserAutenticado", "noAutenticado");
                    this.cookSvc.set("Perfil", "anonimo");
```

Puedo ver en mi app.component.ts su valor y operar,

```
 if (this.cookieSvc.get("UserAutenticado") == null) {
      this.cookieSvc.set('UserAutenticado','noAutenticado',0.00000000001);
      console.log (this.cookieSvc.get('UserAutenticado'));
      } else {
        console.log ("El usuario esta autenticado con id: " + this.cookieSvc.get('UserAutenticado'));
      }
```

Como veis he complicado la respuesta. Tenía que importar y crearme el servicio de cookies en cada componente que deba tener acceso a ella, de esta manera puedo leer o cambiar su valor. Yo pensé que solo se hacia en un componente y NO veía la manera de acceder a ella.

Ahora me queda intentar hacer que la vida de los valores de las cookies y la cookies se borren dependiendo del tiempo (ejemplo a los 30 minutos). Pongo valores como 0.00000000001 pero no se me borran. En fin. Gracias por intentar ayudarme. un saludo