# ¿ Como eliminar cookies al cerrar sesion en Angular?, ¿Como almacenar datos de sesión en Angular?

Tags: angular, session, cookies, sesiones

Gracias a vuestra ayuda en [¿Como utilizar una cookie en Angular 8?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/330048/como-utilizar-una-cookie-en-angular-8) me pude crear una cookie que usa datos de la sesión y datos de privilegio del usuario . Se como hacer log off y que me haga delete de la cookie. Pero si simplemente cierro la ventana del navegador la sesión , los datos se mantiene.
Intento hacer que por tiempo se borre con,

```
  this.cookieSvc.set('UserAutenticado','noAutenticado',0.00000000001);
```

pero no desaparece por tiempo. Supongo no meto bien tiempo con 0.000000001.

¿De que manera puedo hacer para que cerrando ventana se borre la cookie o al menos poner un tiempo para que se destruya?

Gracias

Comment: por que quieres eliminar la cookie? sucede algun error si no la eliminas?

Comment: Porque uso la cookie como medio de almacenar información del usuario y no deseo que otra persona use los privilegios y datos de otra persona si usa ese terminal. Por seguridad. Puedo hacer log off y que se borre. Pero si no es asi, se sale sin hacer una salida así, la cookie no se me elimina.

Comment: Es recomendable usar SessionStorage o LocalStorage en lugar de una cookie ya que se trata de un FRONT-END

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación. Intentare leer algo de lo que me dices. Ni idea. No sabia ni que existía . Si puedes recomendarme algún video o pdf sobre eso , genial. Si no, San Google. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La solución a lo que planteo me la dio el compañero @GFlores98 con su SESSION_STORE.  Yo no sabía que esa opción existía (gracias por abrirme los ojos) y tampoco sabía como usarlo. En   https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/use-localstorage-sessionstorage-using-webstorage-angular4/    encontré el como. Es muy similar a una cookie pero efectivamente ocurre lo que pretendía. Se destruye al cerrar la ventana del navegador.  Gracias.